# add slug beside name in Admin Category Checklists

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, functions, wp-admin

im creating a lot of Categories with the same Name and different slugs, but im having problems identifying which is which in the admin panel, so i came up with the idea of inserting the slug besides the Name in the meta box...im using a taxonomy "portfolio-type"...anyway to do this i need to edit this file: wp-admin/includes/template.php in line 48:

Replace this:

```
esc_html( apply_filters('the_category', $category->name ))
```

With this:

```
esc_html( apply_filters('the_category', $category->name.' - '.$category->slug ))
```

anyway of doing this without editing the core file, lets say a function in my functions.php theme...and to add the slug only to the box containing taxonomy "portfolio-type"..

Answer (score 2):

ok since i didn't have any response im posting the **SOLUTION** my self so it can be useful for others wanting to do the same:

```
add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args', 'display_custom_checklist');
function display_custom_checklist( $args ){
    if ( $args['taxonomy'] == 'portfolio-type' )
    $args['walker'] = new my_custom_walk;
    return $args;
}
class my_custom_walk extends Walker {
    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id'); //TODO: decouple this

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args, $id = 0 ) {
        extract($args);
        if ( empty($taxonomy) )
            $taxonomy = 'category';

        if ( $taxonomy == 'category' )
            $name = 'post_category';
        else
            $name = 'tax_input['.$taxonomy.']';

        $class = in_array( $category->term_id, $popular_cats ) ? ' class="popular-category"' : '';
        $output .= "\n<li id='{$taxonomy}-{$category->term_id}'$class>" . '<label class="selectit"><input value="' . $category->term_id . '" type="checkbox" name="'.$name.'[]" id="in-'.$taxonomy.'-' . $category->term_id . '"' . checked( in_array( $category->term_id, $selected_cats ), true, false ) . disabled( empty( $args['disabled'] ), false, false ) . ' /> ' . esc_html( apply_filters('the_category', $category->name.' - '.$category->slug )) . '</label>';
    }

    function end_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems a round about way , given that `apply_filters( 'the_category', $category->name )` is there, but they do not give us anything else. That filter is USELESS really. it should be something like `apply_filters( 'the_category', $category->name, $category )`. Thanks for the help here mate.